# PHP - Handle for loops for multiple arrays to form a string

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, foreach

I have two multi-diminsional arrays:

```
$rows=[{"id":9,"auditorium_id":10,"row_name":"A","row_seats_no":56,"seat_price":140,.....},{....}]
```

and for each $row there is another array of $spaces for this row:

```
$spaces = [{"id":1,"row_id":9,"starts_at":31,"ends_at":35,"deleted_at":null},{"id":11,"row_id":9,"starts_at":21,"ends_at":25,"deleted_at":null},{"id":21,"row_id":9,"starts_at":10,"ends_at":17,"deleted_at":null}]
```

I try to make a string describes seats and spaces in each row to be returned to javascript, for example for row "A" a string like this should be returned:

```
'AAAAAAAA____AAAAAAAA____AAAAAAAAA', 'row-B', 'row-C', etc...
```

where 'A' char represnt seat and '_' represent empty space.

here is my code:

```
foreach ($auditorium->seatRows as $key => $row) { // inside single row

        $map = $map."'";
        $rowSpaces = RowSpace::where('row_id', '=', $row->id)->get();

        for($i = 1; $i <= $row->row_seats_no; $i++){ // print seat or space, where $i = column_number
            foreach ($rowSpaces as $spaceKey => $rowSpace) {
                if($i > $rowSpaces[$spaceKey]->starts_at && $i < $rowSpaces[$spaceKey]->ends_at)
                {
                    $map = $map."_";
                }
            }

            if($i <= $rowSpaces[$spaceKey]->starts_at || $i > $rowSpaces[$spaceKey]->ends_at)
            {
                $map = $map."{$row->row_name}[{$row->row_name}$i]";
            }

        }

        $map = $map."',";

        $seats = $seats."{$row->row_name}:{'price': {$row->seat_price}, 'classes': '{$row->seatClasses}', 'category': 'VIP'},";

        array_push($rows, $row->row_name);

    }
```

my problem is how to loop through each seat ($i in the for-loop), and know if it is a seat or a space.

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $row->row_seats_no; $i++){ // print seat or space, where $i = column_number
            foreach ($rowSpaces as $spaceKey => $rowSpace) {
                if($i > $rowSpaces[$spaceKey]->starts_at && $i < $rowSpaces[$spaceKey]->ends_at)
                {
                    $map = $map."_";
                }
            }

            if($i <= $rowSpaces[$spaceKey]->starts_at || $i > $rowSpaces[$spaceKey]->ends_at)
            {
                $map = $map."{$row->row_name}[{$row->row_name}$i]";
            }

        }
```

any help is much appreciated

Comment: Are the $rows and $spaces have the same length. For each $row have a $space, and vice versa.

Comment: Is each row have the same total number of seats?

Comment: @KrisRoofe No, $rows and $spaces have different length

Comment: @KrisRoofe Not each $row have the same number of seats, Nor the same number of $spaces .
As the user input these values, I can't guarantee that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem like this:

```
    $rowsArray = [];
    $seatsArray = [];

    foreach ($this->seatRows as $key => $row) { // inside single row
        $rowSpaces = RowSpace::where('row_id', '=', $row->id)->get();
        for($i = 1; $i <= $row->row_seats_no; $i++){ // print seat or space
            foreach ($rowSpaces as $spaceKey => $rowSpace) { // inside space object
                if($i > $rowSpace->starts_at && $i < $rowSpace->ends_at)
                {
                    for($spaceCounter = $i; $spaceCounter < $rowSpace->ends_at; $spaceCounter++){ // while in this space
                        $seatsArray["s$spaceCounter"] = "_";
                    }
                }
            }

            $seatsArray[$i] = "$row->row_name$i";

        }

        $rowsArray[$row->row_name] = $seatsArray;

    }

    // $rowsArray now contain each row with seats and spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do a little different. Instead of each seat searching if it's empty or not. I would assume none is empty, creating array of all seats, them only replacing the empty ones in that array. This is not tested, but would be something like:

```
$return = array();
foreach ($auditorium->seatRows as $key => $row) { // inside single row

    $seatArray = array();

    // CREATING ALL SEATS
    for($i = 1; $i <= $row->row_seats_no; $i++){
        $seatArray[$i] = $row->row_name;
    }

    // CHANGING EMPTY SEATS
    foreach ($rowSpaces as $spaceKey => $rowSpace) {
        // NOT SURE YOU WANT > OR >=
        for($i = $rowSpaces[$spaceKey]->starts_at; $i < $rowSpaces[$spaceKey]->ends_at; $i++)
            $seatArray[$i] = "_";
    }

    $rowSpaces = RowSpace::where('row_id', '=', $row->id)->get();

    // ADDING TO RESULT
    $return[] = implode("", $seatArray);

    $seats = $seats."{$row->row_name}:{'price': {$row->seat_price}, 'classes': '{$row->seatClasses}', 'category': 'VIP'},";

    array_push($rows, $row->row_name);

}
$map = implode(", ", $return);
```

The code had a few bugs (correct a few). I tested with this now. Changed objects to array so I didn't have to create the objects and functions.

```
$data=[["id"=>9,"auditorium_id"=>10,"row_name"=>"A","row_seats_no"=>56,"seat_price"=>140],["id"=>910,"auditorium_id"=>10,"row_name"=>"B","row_seats_no"=>56,"seat_price"=>140]];

$spaces = [["id"=>1,"row_id"=>9,"starts_at"=>31,"ends_at"=>35,"deleted_at"=>null],
            ["id"=>11,"row_id"=>9,"starts_at"=>21,"ends_at"=>25,"deleted_at"=>null],
            ["id"=>21,"row_id"=>9,"starts_at"=>10,"ends_at"=>17,"deleted_at"=>null]];

$return = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $row) { // inside single row

    $seatArray = array();

    // CREATING ALL SEATS
    for($i = 1; $i <= $row['row_seats_no']; $i++){
        $seatArray[$i] = $row['row_name'];
    }

    // CHANGING EMPTY SEATS
    foreach ($spaces as $spaceKey => $rowSpace) {
        // NOT SURE YOU WANT > OR >=
        for($i = $rowSpace['starts_at']; $i < $rowSpace['ends_at']; $i++)
            $seatArray[$i] = "_";
    }

    // ADDING TO RESULT
    $return[] = implode("", $seatArray);

    $seats = $seats."{$row->row_name}:{'price': {$row->seat_price}, 'classes': '{$row->seatClasses}', 'category': 'VIP'},";


}
$map = implode(", ", $return);

echo $map;
```

I'm just not sure if there is anything in the $spaces data in realtion to the row_seat. Is it the row id? If so, it need an if to check that in the foreach cycle for the spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you add all seats first to $seatArray and then add the spaces to the same array. 
I want to loop through seats (your first for loop, where $i is the seat number), and check if at this position exist a seat or a space ?

Comment: It doesn't add the empty seats later, it should replace the filled seats with the empty seats. Giving you the same end result.

Comment: just edited with the working example I tested. But would need a little more info to complete it. It's missing the spaces and row relation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code,

```
foreach($rows as $row)
{
  foreach($row as $seat)
  {
    $arr[$seat['id'] - 1][$seat['row_seats_no'] - 1] = $seat['row_name'];
  }
}
foreach($spaces as $row)
{
  foreach($row as $seat)
  {
    foreach(range($seat['starts_at'] - 1, $seat['ends_at'] - 1) as $index)
    {
      $arr[$seat['row_id'] - 1][$index] = '_';
    }
  }
}
$results = array_map(function($v){return implode($v);}, $arr);
```

Comment: for each $row there is $spaces array , so i can't get the $spaces array outside the foreach($rows as $row )

Comment: Can you simplify your answer please